# Does a square root come out plus/minus even if there is a negative sign outside?

Tags: quadratics, square-numbers

For example: $-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}}$.

Would that give $\pm10x^{10}y^5$ or just $-10x^{10}y^5$?

Comment: It depends on whether $y$ is positive or negative. If $y$ is positive, then $$-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}} = -\sqrt{100} \sqrt{x^{20}} \sqrt{y^{10}} = -10\left| x^{10} \right|\cdot \left| y^5 \right| = -10x^{10}y^5.$$ If $y<0$, you get $10x^{10}y^5$.

Comment: why would it depend on the y? why not the x? why not the coefficient?

Comment: It doesn't depend on $x$, because $x^{10}$ is always positive; we can write $|x^{10}| = x^{10}$. Same for $10$. However, you might have $y^5<0$.

Comment: $-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}}$  is always negative or zero. This fact does NOT depend on $y$ being positive or negative.  Note that
$$-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}}= -\sqrt{100}\sqrt{x^{20}}\sqrt{y^{10}}=-10|x^{10}|.|y^5|= -10|x|^{10}|y|^5$$
We also have $-10|x|^{10}|y|^5=-10x^{10}|y|^5$ because $x^{10}$ is always positive. However, we can not replace $|y|^5$ by $y^5$.

Comment: If $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \geqslant 0$, the expression $\sqrt{x}$ means the **positive** (or zero) square root of $x$, and so $-\sqrt{x}$ means the negative (or zero) square root of $x$.

Answer (score 3):

The symbol $\sqrt{x}$ refers to the principal square root of $x$, which means it only refers to the positive square root.  For example, $\sqrt{9}=3$, not $\pm3$.

In your example, we have $-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}}$.  The principal square root of $100x^{20}y^{10}$ is $|10x^{10}y^5|$ (which is $10x^{10}y^5$ if $y$ is positive (because a positive value of $y$ would make the entire expression positive) and $-10x^{10}y^5$ if $y$ is negative).  Thus, $-\sqrt{100x^{20}y^{10}}=-|10x^{10}y^5|$

Comment: How is the square root of 9 not plus or minus three if negative three by negative three gives you 9?

Comment: Both 3 and -3 are square roots of 9; however, only 3 is the principal square root of 9.

Answer (score 1):

$$-\sqrt{100x^{20} \cdot y^{10}} = -\sqrt{(10 \cdot y^5 \cdot x^{10})^2} = -\operatorname{sgn}(10 \cdot y^5 \cdot x^{10}) \cdot (10 \cdot y^5 \cdot x^{10})$$

Comment: so the answer is -(10x^10y^5) ?